# How to merge two tables keeping rows from first table

Tags: mysql, join, merge

I have following two tables:

table1(a,b,c,d)
table2(a,b,c,d)

My requirement is to merge the two tables; if there are row(s) for combination of columns a and b (only combination of columns a and b, i.e, values for a and b are same) in both tables, keep the rows from first table.

I hope I am clear. Please suggest a query.

Note: Both tables don't have a primary key.

Thanks,

**Update:**

Left join on 's1.a = s2.a AND s1.b = s2.b' giving me duplicate rows and not picking the values from second table where column a and b values are not same. For example if I have 2 rows in table1 as:

11,22,33,44 --
11,55,33,44

and 2 rows in table2 as:

11,22,33,44 --
66,77,44,88

output is 4 rows as:

11,22,33,44 --
11,22,33,44 --
11,55,33,44 --
11,55,33,44

**Update:**

but output should be:

11,22,33,44 --
11,55,33,44 --
66,77,44,88

I thing I need UNION + JOIN + GROUP BY combination here but unable to come up with a right combination/query.

Comment: Tried query suggested by @julie smith. Please see update.

Comment: Please also include what you expect the output to be in the example, just to make sure we understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.* FROM 
(SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1) s1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table2) s2
ON s1.a = s2.a AND s1.b = s2.b
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table1 GROUP BY a,b,c,d
UNION
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table2 GROUP BY a,b,c,d
```

Comment: that's because you have multiple values in table1, you need to make a group by then. and please write your desired output.

Comment: modify your question because you wrote this: only combination of columns a and b, i.e, values for a and b are same) in both tables, keep the rows from first table.